# Vb.net read settings file

Tags: json, vb.net

I created a settings file for my application, like this:

```
username: ProGamingHun
version: 1.0
maxmemory: 1GB
minmemory: 512MB
```

I want to read username, so Dim username = in the settings file: ProGamingHun, how can i do this? The username is unknow leght, because ProGamingHun is a test text. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is this settings file? Are you talking about the Proejct Settings defined in your project or are you talking about a custom file stored somewhere on your PC?

Comment: Yes, this is a costum file (cfg) for my application, this is a program launcher, in this file, the application stored information, like this: username: ProGamingHun etc, and i want read username = ProGamingHun so this search text (username:) and value(ProGamingHun) then in the application username string = ProGamingHun. But i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced, the code you posted as answer, parses the file correctly. You're better off, using regular expressions instead:

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(SettingsRoot + "\config.cfg")
Dim matches = lines.SelectMany(Function(line) Regex.Matches(line, "(.*): (.*)").Cast(Of Match))
Dim dictionary = matches.ToDictionary(Function(match) match.Groups(1).Value, Function(match) match.Groups(2).Value)
```

`dictionary` will now contain the key-value pairs of your settings. Even though this wasn't your original question, you can display them in a message box one by one with the following code:

```
For Each setting In dictionary
    MessageBox.Show(setting.Key & "=" & setting.Value)
Next
```

Nevertheless, I'd suggest you use one of many standard formats for saving settings. This way, you can use existing libraries to parse them:

- XML: [ConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- JSON: [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)
- INI: [INI File Parser](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser)

**EDIT**

To get values from the dictionary into individual variables, use [`dictionary.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) which handles missing keys (settings):

```
Dim username As String = Nothing
dictionary.TryGetValue("username", username)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a correct answer and I'm sory about my "answer" for the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But I would like to read some of the data: dim username as string = nothing; Dim javapath as string = nothing; Dim MaxMemAlloc as string = nothing; Dim MinMemAlloc as string = nothing; Dim Version as string = Nothing, then these strings equals in the config file settings, how i can do this? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @ProGamingHun I added sample code to retrieve value for a single setting from the dictionary.

Comment: Sory, I forgot. Thanks!